# Issue in opening all latest 3 files based on Date Modified using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have trouble opening all the latest 3 files in a folder based on Date Modified using VBA code.
How do I modify the code below so that it can help to open all latest 3 files instead of only latest file based on Date Modified?

```
Dim MyPathClose As String
Dim MyFileClose As String
Dim LatestFileClose As String

Dim LatestDateClose As Date

Dim LMDClose As Date

MyPathClose = "D:\Regina\Case360 reporting automation\Daily Report Closed Testing\"

If Right(MyPathClose, 1) <> "\" Then MyPathClose = MyPathClose & "\"

MyFileClose = Dir(MyPathClose & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)

If Len(MyFileClose) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Do While Len(MyFileClose) > 0
    LMDClose = FileDateTime(MyPathClose & MyFileClose)
    If LMDClose > LatestDateClose Then
        LatestFileClose = MyFileClose
        LatestDateClose = LMDClose
    End If

    MyFileClose = Dir

Loop

Workbooks.Open MyPathClose & LatestFileClose
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help out. Basically use a counter.

Also check [this](https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-loop-files-folder-sub-folders/#:%7E:text=VBA%20code%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a,Looping%20through%20all%20the%20files%20in%20subfolders.%20) to see more looping through file options and how to use FSO.

```
Sub open_last_three()


'Set the file name to a variable
FolderName = "your/path/to/your/folder"

'Set all the references to the FSO Library
Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName)
Set FSOFILE = FSOFolder.Files

Dim filesToOpen As New Collection
'Use For Each loop to loop through each file in the folder
counter = 0
For Each FSOFILE In FSOFILE
    If counter = 3 Then
       Exit For
    End If
    Debug.Print FSOFILE.DateLastModified
    'add it to collection to be used later
    ' you can add more logic to make sure its a csv file, or excel file or whatever before putting into the collection
    filesToOpen.Add FSOFILE.Path
    counter = counter + 1

Next FSOFILE

For Each File In filesToOpen

    Workbooks.Open (File)
    'or call your sub or something
Next File

End Sub
```

Put the file paths into a collection to then be used later for whatever purpose you have for them.

DISCLAIMER: This is assuming your folder is already sorted by date last modified...
if you need it sorted I would recommend outputting the file information onto a sheet and then using vba to call excels built in functions to sort on the column of the date last modified

Comment: Using the code above, I am still unable to open the 3 files with latest Last Modified Date even though I have sorted the files by date last modified. It only open the earliest 3 files based on last modified date.